# In Django I'm trying to display the output of "for loop"

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

In Django I'm trying to display the output of "for loop" one next to another
but  i'm getting the boxes one below the other. how to display the contents of for loop side by side

**template file**

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">

        <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a> </h1>

            {% if post.photo %}
    <img src="{{ post.photo.url }}" class='' height='235' width='235'>
        {% endif %}

        <h3>{{ post.text|safe|linebreaksbr }} </h3>
          
            <p>published on {{post.published_date|date:"D M Y"}}</p>

          <ul>
          <li><form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              
         <a>   <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" > Like </button> </a>
                          {{ post.likes.count }}
          </form></li>

      <li><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">Comments</a>{{ post.approve_comments.count }}
</li>

          </ul>
        <br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**css file**

```
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222222;
}
.content
{

  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ZGu.png
```

Comment: Can you provide an example expected output in your question?

Comment: expected output - https://codepen.io/andymerskin/pen/XNMWvQ @JoeW

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex-direction: row` to your box class or content class in the css file.